# rebase several branch in git at once

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a a linear history with several branches on it.

```
* f4293437a (HEAD -> juanjo/dev) tests
* ab14c2326 modify docker-compose.yml
* 418c340fe [WIP] Initialize test scenes
* fcd36e59e Outpus stuff
* 20c952129 asdf
* bc75c1dc2 asdf
* 6bad5ac7f (origin/juanjo/dev, juanjo/collisions) asdf
* 4b01d63d6 asdf
* e107de108 asdf
* 790362305 (origin/juanjo/attach, juanjo/attachments) asdf
* 33858dbaf asdf2
* c4bbc577c (origin/master) asdf1
```

I have pushed this to gitlab and created a MR to merge `790362305` into master (`c4bbc577c`). I also have a MR for `6bad5ac7f` into master.

Now I have received a a review and I have to modify `33858dbaf` commit. I do that by adding an interactive rebase with a `fixup` commit However, that modifies the history and `juanjo/attachments` doesn't point anymore to the commit following the fixed version of `33858dbaf`. So I have to checkout the branches, reset them to point to the correct commits and push again to gitlab (with --force, to override the old history so the commits fixing reviews doesn't appear in history)

Is there anyway to automatically reset the branches to the correct commit when doing the rebase?

Comment: The short answer is no. People keep looking for a tool to do this. I wrote one myself, that handled certain special cases that I was working with, but it's *extremely hard* to do it "right" (it was impossible before, but with the fancy new rebase-merges mode it should be possible now). Building a proper tool to do this might make a lot of people happy...

Comment: Your particular case is one of the simpler ones, that my ancient tool managed (it was for Git 1.8 or so though and I'm not sure what I did with it).

Comment: @torek What about using `replace` followed by `git-filter-repo`?

Comment: So ideally, something like gerrit does, which adds a new SHA to the commit message, so when you modify the history, you can still identify matching commits by comparing that secondary SHA should work, right? But nothing out of the box

Comment: @TTT: probably should work but seems both heavyweight *and* not as ideal as the kind of "multi-rebase" I was aiming for (where you designate some set of branch names as "associated" and have a `git rebase --multibranch` mode that uses the interactive machinery, letting you pick, edit, squash/fixup, and otherwise reshuffle commits).

Comment: @jjcasmar: that's another possible way to handle this. It's not entirely clear where this secondary hash ID might come from (gerrit's method of generating it is a little odd, but does work as a sort of proof of concept).

Comment: that --multibranch thing is something already or is something that you are aiming to develop?